# Calculus rate of water filling a hemisphere

Tags: calculus, derivatives

A large hemispherical wok has a diameter of 60cm. It is being filled at a constant rate of $50cm^3/s$. At what rate is the radius of the surface of the water increasing when the height of the water is 10cm?

Note: The volume of a 'cap' of a sphere is $V = \frac{\pi*h^2}{R-h/3}$
Where $h$ is the height of the water and $R$ is the radius of the sphere.

I know this question is to do with related rates of change, and I am being asked to find out $dr/dt$, I am given $dV/dt = 50$. And i find dV/dh to be $60*\pi*h - \pi*h^2$

The next step on the answer sheet is to make $r^2 = 30^2-(30-h)^2$ but I do not understand where they have gotten this from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the image below:

[image]
The red circled triangle has sides $R$ (the radius of the sphere), $r$ (the radius of the water surface) and $R-h$ (where $h$ is the water height). Pythagoras tells you that $R^2 = r^2 + (R-h)^2.$